# element not appends in body on window onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, notifications, zooming, window-resize

I have been created the function which detects the screen zoom-in or zoom-out function. I am trying if window zoom == 100 or is in normal size the notification will remove else it append instantly.
In my code, it's working perfectly but it not working on window load, for showing the demo and result I have to click `ctrl+` or `ctrl-`.
I am trying as window load it auto decide and append if window zoom, not 100 or normal.

Please help me with how I fix this?

```js
function informationbar(percentage, zoomstatus) {
  $("body").append('<div id="informationbar" style="top: 0px;"><a href="javascript:informationbar.close()"><img src="#" style="width: 14px; height: 14px; float: right; border: 0; margin-right: 5px" /></a>You are using the window screen on ' + percentage + '% ' + zoomstatus + ' resolution, might some options are not visible properly on this current resolution please fit the screen on 100% as this our highly recommendation.</div>');
}

$(window).resize(function() {
  var browserZoomLevel = Math.round(window.devicePixelRatio * 100);
  if (browserZoomLevel !== '100') {
    if (browserZoomLevel > "100") {
      var status = "ZoomIn";
    } else {
      var status = "ZoomOut";
    }

    informationbar(browserZoomLevel, status);
  } else {
    $("div#informationbar").remove();
  }
});

var browserZoomLevel = Math.round(window.devicePixelRatio * 100);
if (browserZoomLevel == '100') {
  $("div#informationbar").remove();
} else {
  if (browserZoomLevel > "100") {
    var status = "ZoomIn";
  } else {
    var status = "ZoomOut";
  }

  informationbar(browserZoomLevel, status);
}
```

```css
#informationbar {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  width: 100 %;
  text - indent: 5 px;
  padding: 5 px 0;
  background - color: lightyellow;
  border - bottom: 1 px solid black;
  font: bold 12 px Verdana;
}

* html# informationbar {
  /*IE6 hack*/
  position: absolute;
  width: expression(document.compatMode=="CSS1Compat" ? document.documentElement.clientWidth + "px": body.clientWidth + "px");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using `!==` to compare numbers and strings, e.g. `browserZoomLeveL !== '100'` where `browserZoomLevel = Math.round(...)`.

That will **always** give `false`, since the a string isn't a number, and `===` is strict about types. You should replace `=== '100'` with just `=== 100`.

Comment: It not working when I used `https://jsfiddle.net/fodupmgh/`